# Find format of clipboard image in Java

Tags: java, image, clipboard, image-formats

I'm getting images from clipboard using this:

```
if(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)){
       ImageIcon IMG = new ImageIcon((BufferedImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor));
}
```

Now I want to save this image in disk using `ImageIO.write`;
How can I find image format (JPG,PNG,GIF,...) to use in `ImageIO.write` as `formatName` ?

Thanks

Comment: [This Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447035/java-get-image-extension-type-using-bufferedimage-from-url) might help.

Comment: @Gus: unfortunately this doesn't work when image is came from clipboard; the `ImageIO.getImageReaders(imageIconObject)` returns an empty iterator!

Comment: In short, this is simply not possible. When you retrieve the image from the clipboard, it is in the `java.awt.Image` format. This is Java's representation of image data, completely independent of the original format of whatever image file this data came from. You can write the image to disk in whatever format you choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mime type of the content of the clipboard when checked via

```
.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)
```

is [image/x-java-image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#imageFlavor) (but [OS vendors do not need to follow MIME types for clipboards](http://books.google.de/books?id=Ojk25QoiTrYC&pg=PA403&lpg=PA403&dq=clipboard+mimetype+java&source=bl&ots=RJ4lX3VEON&sig=75UmRnqnR_sLuqwnoC58YWZ6KyM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V6fkULT3C8XhtQaCgIGoCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=clipboard%20mimetype%20java&f=false)).

I found two ways to supposedly get an image from a clipboard and write it to a file:

1. Using a helper method found in this blog post: [The nightmares of getting images from the Mac OS X clipboard using Java](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/2/8/The-nightmares-of-getting-images-from-the-Mac-OS-X-clipboard-using-Java).

   ```
   Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()

   ImageIcon IMG = new ImageIcon((BufferedImage)    
   clip.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor));
   BufferedImage bImage = getBufferedImage(IMG.getImage());
   ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", new File("/tmp/test.png"));
   ```

   The `getBufferedImage` method looks like this:

   ```
   public static BufferedImage getBufferedImage(Image img) {
       if (img == null) {
           return null;
       }
       int w = img.getWidth(null);
       int h = img.getHeight(null);
       // draw original image to thumbnail image object and 
       // scale it to the new size on-the-fly 
       BufferedImage bufimg = new BufferedImage(w, h, 
           BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       Graphics2D g2 = bufimg.createGraphics();
       g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
           RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
       g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
       g2.dispose();
       return bufimg;
   }
   ```
2. Via Transferable. Note that this runs on OS X but produces an empty image of the correct size:

   ```
   Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
   Transferable content =
       clip.getContents(null);
   BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) content.getTransferData(
       DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
   ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("/tmp/test.png"));
   ```