# To get image type in java

Tags: java, image, types

I need to deturmine type of image in my java programm. I tried to use [Java get image extension/type using BufferedImage from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447035/java-get-image-extension-type-using-bufferedimage-from-url) this, but it always returned me jpeg fomat, even if i have .ico or .bmp, or .gif image. Is there a better way?

Comment: FYI : Don't rely upon a MIME type.

Comment: @Lion why shouldn't we?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `split()` function.

This function is used to split a string into an array. The function takes in one parameter which is with which character we want to split the string into. So in your case it would be:

```java
String[] path = path_of_image.split("\\."); /* Needs escaping because it uses regex */
String ext = path[path.length - 1];
```

Now the `String` ext have your file extension.

Comment: A dot in parameter to the `split()` method needs to be escaped. The `split()` method works on regex.

Comment: Need two back slashes like so `split("\\.")`.

Comment: My problem is that method, that i used to get image type always returned wrong type. It returned jpeg, then real type was icon, or gif, or something else.

Comment: If I understood you correctly then the method above is not any wrong instead there's some real problem in your code and obivo, your image type couldn't be wrong so go through your code one more time.