# Can I tell what the file type of a BufferedImage originally was?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

In my code, I have a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) that was loaded with the [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class like so:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File (filePath);
```

Later on, I want to save it to a byte array, but the `ImageIO.write` method requires me to pick either a GIF, PNG, or JPG format to write my image as (as described in the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)).

I want to pick the same file type as the original image. If the image was originally a GIF, I don't want the extra overhead of saving it as a PNG. But if the image was originally a PNG, I don't want to lose translucency and such by saving it as a JPG or GIF. Is there a way that I can determine from the BufferedImage what the original file format was?

I'm aware that I could simply parse the file path when I load the image to find the extension and just save it for later, but I'd ideally like a way to do it straight from the BufferedImage.

Comment: Muhaha, enjoy the [alpha channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386446).

Comment: You can access the image type and create a `BufferedImage` using an `InputStream` and `ImageIO`. Just convert the `File` to an `InputStream` first. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36770963/1625820

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @JarrodRoberson says, the `BufferedImage` has no "format" (i.e. no file format, it does have one of several pixel formats, or pixel "layouts").  I don't know Apache Tika, but I guess his solution would also work.

However, if you prefer using only `ImageIO` and not adding new dependencies to your project, you could write something like:

```
ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(filePath));

try {
    Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);

    if (readers.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = readers.next();

        try {
            reader.setInput(input);

            BufferedImage image = reader.read(0);  // Read the same image as ImageIO.read

            // Do stuff with image...

            // When done, either (1):
            String format = reader.getFormatName(); // Get the format name for use later
            if (!ImageIO.write(image, format, outputFileOrStream)) {
                // ...handle not written
            }
            // (case 1 done)

            // ...or (2):
            ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWriter(reader); // Get best suitable writer

            try {
                ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputFileOrStream);

                try {
                    writer.setOutput(output);
                    writer.write(image);
                }
                finally {
                    output.close();
                }
            }
            finally {
                writer.dispose();
            }
            // (case 2 done)
        }
        finally {
            reader.dispose();
        }
    }
}
finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Choosing this one as the asnwer because, although Tika may be more reliable, I don't care to add a 25 MB dependency so this is ultimately a better solution for me and I'm alright with "reliable enough". Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

#### BufferedImage does not have a "format"

Once the bytes have been translated into a `BufferedImage` the *format* of the source file is completely lost, the contents represent a raw byte array of the pixel information nothing more.

#### Solution

You should use the [`Tika`](http://tika.apache.org/) library to determine the format from the original byte stream before the `BufferedImage` is created and not rely on file extensions which can be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

One could encapsulate the BufferedImage and related data in class instance(s) like so:

```
final public class TGImage
{

  public String naam;
  public String filename;
  public String extension;    
  public int layerIndex;
  public Double scaleX;
  public Double scaleY;
  public Double rotation;
  public String status;
  public boolean excluded;

  public BufferedImage image;


  public ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<>(5);

  public TGImage()
  {
    naam = "noname";
    filename = "";
    extension ="";
    image = null;
    scaleX = 0.0;
    scaleY = 0.0;
    rotation = 0.0;
    status = "OK";
    excluded = false;
    layerIndex = 0;
    addHistory("Created");
  }

  final public void addHistory(String str)
  {
    history.add(TGUtil.getCurrentTimeStampAsString() + " " + str);
  }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
public TGImage loadImage()
    {
        TGImage imgdat = new TGImage();

        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "gif", "tif");
        fc.setFileFilter(filter);
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

        int result = fc.showOpenDialog(this);  // show file chooser

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Selected file extension is " + TGUtil.getFileExtension(file));

            if (TGUtil.isAnImageFile(file))
            {
                //System.out.println("This is an Image File.");

                try
                {
                    imgdat.image = ImageIO.read(file);
                    imgdat.filename = file.getName();
                    imgdat.extension = TGUtil.getFileExtension(file); 

                    info("image has been loaded from file:" + imgdat.filename);

                } catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(TGImgPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    imgdat.image = null;
                    info("File not loaded IOexception: img is null");
                }

            } else
            {
                imgdat = null;
                info("File not loaded: The requested file is not an image File.");
            }
        }
        return imgdat;
    }
```

Then you have everything relevant together in TGImage instance(s).
and perhaps use it in an imagelist like so:

```
ArrayList<TGImage> images = new ArrayList<>(5);
```