# Do certain image file types always correspond with certain BufferedImage constant types?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

The [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class in Java contains a `getType()` method which returns an integer correlating with a BufferedImage constant type variable describing some information about how the image is encoded (you can look at the [BufferedImage source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.java.html) to determine what number corresponds to what constant type variable). For instance, if it returns the integer corresponding with `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, then that means that the BufferedImage is an 8-bit RGB image with no alpha and with blue, green, and yellow each being represented by 3 bits.

Some of these image types seem to correlate with certain properties of a particular format. For instance, `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` says that it is created from "a 256-color 6/6/6 color cube palette". This sounds a lot like GIF images, which are created from 256 colors.

Curious, I scanned several hundred photos on my hard drive and converted each of them to a BufferedImage, using `ImageIO.read(File file)`, then called `BufferedImage.getType()` on them. I determined that there were only a few BufferedImage types that were generated from certain image types. The results were as follows:

**JPG:** TYPE_3BYTE_BGR, TYPE_BYTE_GRAY

**PNG:** TYPE_3BYTE_BGR, TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, TYPE_4BYTE_BGRA

**GIF:** TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED

While it looks like both JPGs and PNGs shared some similar BufferedImage constant types, only a PNG in my test resulted in a `TYPE_4BYTE_BGRA` and every GIF resulted in a `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`.

I'm not too familiar with image formats and it's true that my sample size isn't all that large. So I figured I'd ask: assuming that an image is properly formatted, do certain image types always result in BufferedImages with certain constant types? To provide a specific example, would a properly formatted GIF image always correspond to `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`? Or is it possible for all properly formatted images to correspond with all of the BufferedImage constant types?

Comment: I think it would help potential answerers, if you described what problem you were trying to solve with this information...

Comment: @haraldK, this was originally derived from my other question where I was wondering if you could determine the original image file format that made up a BufferedImage. I since discovered the .getType() method which seemed to maybe indicate the original image type, but I wanted to ask for a clarification on its usage because I had serious doubts that this was a reliable indicator (and as your answer indicates, it indeed isn't).

Comment: The answer should have made everything clear (and one can say that in the end, it all depends on what the *decoder* what type you receive). Just as an aside: Reading PNG files that contain *transparency* will often result in the type `TYPE_CUSTOM`, which does not tell you anything. And maybe more important: When you want to *paint* the loaded images, you should consider converting them to `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, because for other types, the painting may be horribly slow. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391353/get-color-of-each-pixel-of-an-image-using-bufferedimages/22391951#22391951

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Do] certain image types always result in `BufferedImage` with certain constant types?

As in [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21057191/1428606); **No, there is no direct relationship between the `BufferedImage` types and file formats**.

> Or is it possible for all properly formatted images to correspond with all of the `BufferedImage` constant types?

**Basically, yes.** Of course, a color image would lose information if converted to gray, 
a 16 bit per sample image would lose precision if converted to 8 bits per sample, etc.

---

However, different file formats have different ways of storing pixels and colors, and usually a certain `BufferedImage` type more closely represent the "layout" used in the file format.

**Let's use your GIF example:**

The storage "layout" of a GIF (before applying LZW compression) is normally closest to that of `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`, so that is usually the "cheapest" conversion to do in Java. For GIFs with up to 16 colors, `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` would work just as well. And it's always possible for a GIF to be decoded into `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` or `TYPE_INT_ARGB` (or even `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` or `TYPE_INT_RGB` if no transparent color).

In other words, the type of image depends on the decoder, and in some cases (like for [the `ImageIO` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReadParam.html#setDestinationType(javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier))) the user.

To summarize, what you have found, is that the GIF plugin for ImageIO (`GIFImageReader`) by default will decode a GIF with more than 16 colors to `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`. Using a different decoder/framework may yield different results.

---

A little bit of history that might enlighten the curious reader:

The types of `BufferedImage`s where not modeled to correspond to image formats. They were modeled to correspond to display hardware. An image having the same pixel layout as the display hardware is always going to be faster to display. Other layouts would first need to go through some kind of conversion. Now with modern display hardware being very fast, this is of course less of a concern, but in "ancient" times this was important.

Incidentally, many "ancient" image formats were created ad hoc, or for specific applications running on specific display hardware. Because of this, the pixel layout of the display hardware were often used in the file format. Again, because no conversion was needed, and it was the fastest/simplest thing to implement.

So, yes, there is a relationship. It's just not a direct "given A => B" relationship, it's a "given A *and* C => B".

Comment: So to clarify, a gif at least will always result in a certain type of BufferedImage, while PNGs can be just about every type?

Comment: No, there is no direct relationship between the BufferedImage types and file formats.

Comment: I'm confused. You said that the storage "layout" of a GIF is that of `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`. Isn't that a relationship between the two? Or are we using the definition of a relationship differently?

Comment: You are twisting my words. Don't do that. I said the layout of GIF "is *closest to*" (in Java, that is), not "is". And I said "no *direct* relationship", not "no relationship". The relationship you are talking about is like: Does Ferrari make red cars? Yes (and red is a common color for Ferraris). But: Are all Ferraris red? No. Is Ferrari the only car maker making red cars? Again, no.

Comment: I didn't intend to twist your words. Like I said, we seem to be using different definitions of what a relationship, or a direct relationship, means. I appreciate you modifying your answer to further clarify what you were intending, especially by adding that it's just the format that the BufferedImage type is just the one that ImageIO has chosen to use, but that a different decoder might choose something differently.