# What is the default type of a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

As we know, there are some types of BufferedImage like BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB , BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB and so on.

If I only use

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new pngFile(filePath));
```

What is the type of image.Does it has something to do with the file's format like PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getType()` method from `BufferedImage` objects:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

// ...

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
System.out.println(image.getType());
```

According to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType%28%29):

> Returns the image type. If it is not one of the known types, TYPE_CUSTOM is returned.

On OpenJDK 11 running on x86_64 linux platform the above code snippet returns `BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` (integer value 6).

**Edit:**

Regarding the last question, you can read this [well-elaborated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21077575/2670792). In short:

> No, there is no direct relationship between the `BufferedImage` types and file formats.

Comment: OP is looking for image format such as png, gif, jpg etc or want to know about file's format.

Comment: @Braj read carefully. He wants to know the type of the image (one of the types he mentioned). He also wants to know if this type has something to do with image's format.

Comment: @Braj  I disagree.  The OP seems to mistakenly think the file type *relates* to the image type.  While certain file types like JPEG will never be an image type that supports transparency (e.g. `TYPE_INT_ARGB`) the rest of the field is pretty wide open, AFAIU.