# How to get the extension file of Input Stream

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a code

```
var test = Base64.getDecoder.decode(base64);   
ByteArrayInputStream(test);
var input_stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(test);
Logger.debug(test.getClass.getSimpleName)
```

How do I get the file extension of the variable input_stream?

Comment: `ByteArrayInputStream` does not have a file extension. It has not relation to files at all. Your second line is redundant, it does nothing. What is the content of `base64` variable?

Comment: Hi content of base64 is an image in base64 string

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are asking how to determine the image file format from its bytes.

This has already been answered here: [Java get image extension/type using BufferedImage from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447035/java-get-image-extension-type-using-bufferedimage-from-url)

I would not use the term "file extension" to refer to the file format -- while many systems (including Windows) conventionally use the file name extension to indicate the file format, you cannot always rely on this convention, and these are two separate concepts. I found the above question by Googling "`java how to detect image type`"

Good luck!